# meaning of #varName# in sql (placed in xml tag)

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

Just wondering what `#variableName#` represents in the SQL placed inside XML files?
So far I haven't had any luck on Google.

Thanks

Comment: I feel it's a specific implementation on your project. Ask your co-workers for some insight.

Comment: If it's not supposed to be a comment, then is the data used in a ColdFusion application? In that programming language, wrapping a variable with "#" will output its value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `#` character is not special in T-SQL.  For example, this works just fine:

```
declare @#hello# integer = 7
select @#hello#
```

I have not heard of a common naming convention that uses this. It may mean something to the original author, but not sure what.